# Connection reset by Cloudflare when building Packer image

Tags: packer

I am trying to build a packer image for a digital ocean droplet, however when the build process finishes, it fails to create image (from what I can tell, that is a Cloudflare IP)

Any idea why this is happening or what I can do to investigate it further?

```
==> digitalocean: Gracefully shutting down droplet...
==> digitalocean: Error shutting down droplet: Post https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/198964166/actions: read tcp 10.0.2.15:44558->104.16.181.15:443: read: connection reset by peer
==> digitalocean: Destroying droplet...
==> digitalocean: Deleting temporary ssh key...
Build 'digitalocean' errored: Error shutting down droplet: Post https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/198964166/actions: read tcp 10.0.2.15:44558->104.16.181.15:443: read: connection reset by peer
```